# Mac OS Mojave phpunit 8.0.1 symfony

Tags: phpunit, php-7.2

After the installation of PHPunit 8.0.1 I got this error:

```
Fatal error: Declaration of Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\KernelTestCase::tearDown() must be compatible with PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase::tearDown()
```

I am using PHP 7.2

Answer (score 2):

Your tearDown function is not compatible with the function you extend.
You have to add the return type in order to implement the same declaration.

```
protected function tearDown(): void
```

See also documentation https://phpunit.de/announcements/phpunit-8.html section "Return Type of Template Methods"